# "На буферной зоне" или "в буферной зоне"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика, выбор-слов, предлоги

Как правильно написать: "Этаж в буферной зоне - несоответствие" или "этаж на буферной зоне - несоответствие" ?

Comment: Как заголовок связан с вопросом?

Comment: Хотелось бы понять о чем речь, для этого нужен контекст. А абстрактно говоря, "на зоне" — это из воровского жаргона (мотать срок на зоне).

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, что правильно говорить **этаж в буферной зоне** (если речь, конечно, идет о здании).

Небоскребы уже более двадцати лет снабжают "интеллектом", который отвечает за работу всех инженерных систем и внимательно следит за микроклиматом внутри высотных зданий. В жару, когда солнце слишком сильно греет фасад, умная система "прячет" здание в жалюзи, а также запускает дополнительные возможности охлаждения.

Буферные зоны участвуют в создании комфортного микроклимата. В них находятся своеобразные форточки-клапана(1), которые открываются при определенной скорости ветра и при определенной температуре наружного воздуха. Это дает возможность создавать естественный сквозняк в буферных зонах, что ведет к понижению температуры в здании и снижает нагрузку на систему его охлаждения. Помещения таким образом хорошо инсолированы(2).
Такие экозоны располагаются по периметру башни, занимая по высоте сразу два этажа и до 11 процентов площади каждого уровня. Они доходят практически до самого верха – до 76 этажа небоскреба из 87.

Получается, что **этажи** с семьдесят седьмого по восемьдесят седьмой не находятся (в чем?) **в буферной зоне** здания.

[Буферная зона центра Лахта](https://lakhtacenter.livejournal.com/tag/%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0)
[Дом в Париже с буферной зоной](http://www.archilenta.ru/?act=1&nwid=3105)

---

(1) [Клапан](https://diffc_ru.academic.ru/2750/%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD), *мн.* кл**а**паны, *род.* кл**а**панов и *в профессиональной речи* клапан**а**, клапан**о**в.
(2) [Инсоляция](https://strelka.com/ru/magazine/2017/03/30/vocabulary-insolyaciya) — степень освещённости солнечным светом зданий, сооружений и их внутренних помещений.

Comment: Согласен, что в зоне, а не на зоне. Но данной статье скорее зона на этаже, чем этаж в зоне.